# facebook connect on mobile

Tags: c#, facebook, fbconnect

i want users can log in my website throw FB connect ON MOBILE
 but it's seem that it work only on smart Phone (exmple iphone )

is it possibale that it will work in all Phone that use wap ?

thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I believe you can, I suggest taking a look over at their documentation.

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect_for_Mobile_Web

It seems the only difference is that instead of a popup or modal you just redirect them to facebook and then are redirected back after authorizing, sort of twitter like.

Comment: wiki.developers.facebook.com is now dead.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone reading this thread in 2011 - the link to the mobile web documentation above no longer works - it is a circular redirect loop that always takes you back to the regular desktop documentation.